# Unpacking into a list from a comma-separated right hand side

Tags: python

The syntax:

```
>>> x = 1, 2
```

creates a tuple where `x -> (1, 2)`. Is it possible to create a `list` in this way? I know that you can do the two-liner:

```
>>> x = 1, 2
>>> x = list(x)
```

Is there a more efficient operation for this purpose?

I'm thinking no, since a simple:

```
>>> 1, 2, 3
(1, 2, 3)
```

shows a tuple being generated, so now I am thinking that something like:

```
>>> a, b = x, y
```

may not be wholly efficient, since the right-hand side generates a tuple first. Is this true?

Comment: Why can't you just do `x = [1, 2]` ?

Comment: It's probably worth clarifying that `x = 1, 2` is no kind of unpacking. It's just assignment, plain and simple. _Technically_ you can unpack the entire tuple into a list, as in [InSync's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76957456/418413); however, that would be a pretty obscure way to write `x = [1, 2]`. OTOH, if you want _part_ of the tuple as a list, and not the whole, then unpacking is a good solution.

Comment: Clarifying further, `>>> 1, 2, 3` doesn't show "a tuple being generated". Parentheses aren't what make a thing a tuple. [Commas are what makes a thing a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists).

Comment: So when I do something like `a, b = b, a`, is the right-hand side first made into a tuple and then unpacked into the left @kojiro?

Comment: @user129393192 Would you say in `x = "hello"` that the right hand side is _made into a string_? It's parsed as a string, so in some sense it's not _wrong_, but it gives the impression of a wrong understanding. I would not say the right-hand side is _made into a tuple_. It just _is_ a tuple. But it's true that it is unpacked into the left, in your example.

Comment: @kojiro my question is more akin to: if I have `a, b = b, a`. Is a `tuple` object *constructed* (because it didn't exist before) and then unpacked? This tuple then has no references to it and is present for garbage collection.

Comment: @user129393192 yes. Try looking at it in the disassembler. `import dis; dis.dis(f)` where `f` is a function that unpacks a tuple such as `a,b=1,2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this?

```py
*x, = 1, 2

print(x)  # [1, 2]
```

It's called [*extended iterable unpacking*](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/) or *starred assignment*, and, yes, the trailing comma is necessary.

Regardless, you may instead drop that comma in favor of square brackets:

```py
[*x] = 1, 2
```

This works exactly the same.

Comment: What does the trailing comma do here, and in similar expressions?

Comment: @user129393192 It is similar to the trailing comma in a single-element tuple: `(1,)`. What do you mean by "similar expressions"?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. It's to distinguish the `*x` unpacking from an assignment? For `a = (1,)` it makes sense to distinguish it from `1`, but this is left-hand side for `*x,`

Comment: @user129393192 The PEP says that "*[i]t is also an error to use the starred expression as a lone assignment target*" but doesn't explain any further. This is probably due to `x = [1, 2]` being more favorable.

Comment: I see. I wonder why it is that way still. I don't see any conflicts with other syntax. You made the follow up about the square brackets, but I only see that mentioned once, inexplicitly, within the PEP and not a part of the grammar. It seems the implementation only allows it as `exprlist: star_expr (',' star_expr)* [',']`

Comment: @user129393192 It seems that this usage is reflected in the chain `assignment` - `star_targets` - `star_target` - `target_with_star_atom` - `star_atom` - `'[' [star_targets_list_seq] ']'` - `','.star_target+ [',']`/`star_target (',' star_target)* [',']` ([convenient link](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/grammar.html)). I'm not really sure though.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the link. I was just wondering how you knew about it.

Comment: @user129393192 `*x = 1, 2` leads to a `SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple`. That and a while reading the PEP/specs.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that doing a simple:
`x = [1, 2, 3]`
would work for your purposes.

It can still work for the following:
`x1, x2, x3 = x`

where then:
`x1 = 1`
`x2 = 2`
`x3 = 3`